# how to hide params in $http POST method

Tags: java, spring, http, post

how to hide params in $http post method . If i use data instead params as in given example , I have change nearly 400 server side request getters from request.getParameter("key") to request.getReader() ;
I have a situation here . We are about to migrate from `request.getParameter` to `request.getReader` . 
Reason : To remove form parameters from requet URL .

from this : `http://localhost:8080/myApp/test.do?test1=abc&test2=def`

to this :`http://localhost:8080/myApp/test.do`

here is what i have achieved  .
sample request (old) :

```
            $scope.myJson = {
        'abc' : '123',
        'def' : '456',
    };

    $http({

        method : 'POST',
        url : 'test.do',
        param : {
            'test1' : $scope.myJson,
        },
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }). success(function(data, status, headers, config) {


    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

sample request new

```
            $scope.myJson = {
        'abc' : '123',
        'def' : '456',
    };

    $http({

        method : 'POST',
        url : 'test.do',
        data: {
            'test1' : $scope.myJson,
        },
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }). success(function(data, status, headers, config) {


    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

As You can see i have changed param to data .

Server Side (old);

```
final String myJson= request.getParameter("test1");
```

Server Side (new) :

```
     StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
      String line = null;
      try {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
          jb.append(line);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();/*report an error*/ }

      try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jb.toString());
        JSONObject jsonObj1 =jsonObj.getJSONObject("test1");
        String test1= jsonObj1.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is this the way to handle this scenerio ?We Have around 400+ services in application . Any Quick Workaround ?

EDIT 1 :

```
public class myController extends AjaxBaseController {


    @Override
    public ModelAndView executeAjaxCall(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {


        final String test1= request.getParameter("test1");               

        final InputParam loginParam = JsonUtil.convertPojo(test1,InputParam .class); // POJO class
//other logics 

    };
}
```

Comment: You are missing the entire point of Spring MVC.  You should almost never work directly with the HttpServletRequest, In Spring controllers you define which information that request has, and Spring does all the parsing, so you only need to worry about the logic.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any (good) way around changing your controllers (and why on earth are you processing parameters by hand, this is what Spring is for).

In Spring params are parsed into separate method arguments with `@RequestParam` like this:

```
public String doWork(@RequestParam("name") String value, .......)
```

You want to change this so the backend instead receives JSON data, which is Spring are handled using `@RequestBody` supported by `HttpMessageConverter`  which is chosen based on the posted `Context-Type` header. And looks like this

```
public String doWork(@RequestBody MyDto object)
```

I know the Spring web stack pretty well, and I could probably find a way around this, but it is such a bad idea, and would only give you problems in the future (when some one wants to post a list from JSON), that I will not even try to come up with a solution.

One thing that may make the conversion go faster if you have 400 controller methods, so to skip the DTO step and use a Map like this

```
public String doRequest(@RequestBody Map<String, String> map) {
   String abc = map.get("abc");
   String def = map.get("def");
}
```

Comment: Actually its a migrated project which was partially completed already .I Have updated my answer .Look at EDIT1 : .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this "hiding" that you are doing is not going to make your API any more secure.  If someone can see the HTTP requests, it is not significantly more difficult to see params sent in the body versus those sent in the request URL.

(If you want to hide the params from third parties, use HTTPS.  If you want to hide them from the user .... sorry, but that is not possible.)

---

Assuming that what you are doing is worthwhile, AND you want to keep the recoding effort in changing the server side to a minimum, then I would suggest that you design a utility / helper method that does the equivalent of your "new" server side code.  Here is a starting point ...

```
public JSONObject getRequestParams(Request request) {
    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            jb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        /*report / handle error*/ 
    }

    try {
        return = new JSONObject(jb.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        /* report / handle error */
    }   
}
```

Then your particular example can be coded as:

```
final JSONObject myJson = 
       getRequestParams(request).getJSONObject("test1");
```

Depending on the range of parameters you need to deal with, you could have different helper methods to fetch a single parameter, multiple parameters, handle "optional" and "mandatory" parameters, generate consistent status codes and error reports for the response, and so on.

The general principle is to examine a representative sample of your 400 or so REST API calls, and take the time to design your helper methods so that you can extract parameters concisely and efficiently.

---

**UPDATE** - I didn't notice that this was a Spring MVC project.  That changes thing considerably.  If you use Spring MVC's request mapping infrastructure (properly), that will handle parameters passed in the URL and the body transparently; see Klaus Groenbaek's answer.

Comment: yes .. this is what i have in mind . i was actually thinking if could be handled better in $http itself . Actually the new requirement is to structure the api call where params are not put along with request URL.

Answer (score 0):

You must change queryParameters to FormParam

Comment: You mean to change param : {"name" :"abc"} to data : {"name" : "abc"} ?

Comment: no, there are 5strategies to send data in http 
https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html